# How ignore empty array elements for length calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JS:**

```
var personnesAAjouter = [];

personnesAAjouter[idUtilisateur] = [];
personnesAAjouter[idUtilisateur]['nom'] = nomUtilisateur;
personnesAAjouter[idUtilisateur]['prenom'] = prenomUtilisateur;
personnesAAjouter[idUtilisateur]['email'] = emailUtilisateur;
```

For exemple, if I add an user with `idUtilisateur = 102`, length of `personneAAjouter` is `102`.

Maybe because keys are integer and that Javascript use keys to get the array length?

It exists a way to ignore each empty elements for length calculation?

Thank's for help!

Comment: how about ""+idUtilisateur

Comment: Already try and problem is the same.

Comment: could you try "_"+id...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` like below:

```js
let arr=[];
arr[5]=1;
console.log(arr.length);
let myLength=arr.reduce((acc,cv)=>(cv)?acc+1:acc,0);
console.log(myLength);
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer!

Comment: @N.Lamblin Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: @vibhor1997a sorry I have trouble understanding how `reduce` works. Because reduce give a length right? And after `reduce` arr is set without empty elements?

Comment: Have a look at [Array.prototype.reduce](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1wPuunK_YAhUlDcAKHfSjDMYQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce&usg=AOvVaw1rZ36_gx-fT2lgEYKcfeI5) to undestand it.

Comment: Thank's, sorry for the disturbance.

Comment: Welcome anytime :P

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript arrays are object. Arrays have a `length` property whose value is the highest integer key present in the object + 1.

So `array.length` does not return the number of elements in the array but only the value of that property.

To actually count the number of elements in your array you could use something like this:

```
var arrayCount = function(myArray) {
    var count = 0;
    myArray.forEach(function(val) {
        count++;
    });
    return count;
}
```

Comment: It exists another strucure which can solve my problem?

Comment: You could use the function I added in my answer to count actual elements, or maybe you could use an object, because you cannot have empty keys in a JS object.

Comment: Thank's for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `arr.filter(x=>1).length` instead of just `arr.length`

```js
myArray = ["a","b"]
delete array[1] // deletes "b", but leaves an 'empty' slot 'existing'

console.log(myArray)
// ["a", empty]

myArray.length
// -> 2

// this is a filter that returns true for every item, but is only run for
// items that aren't empty. Note that it is non-mutating; it creates a 
// new array in memory, measures its length, and then lets it disappear
// into the void.
myArray.filter(x=>1).length // -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use filter instead to keep the data type consistent (especially in typescript)

```
let stringArr = [];
stringArr[3] = "abc";
const result = stringArr.filter(word => word !== undefined);
```